# Bypassing JWT Authentication in debug mode ASP.NET CORE .NET CORE 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

We have a microservice utilizing JWT Tokens to authorize a user when they are requesting data or performing an action in the controller.

Within the controller we have specified that certain Http actions have an [Authorize] attribute on them to prevent certain users from accessing those controller methods.

What we are having difficulty with right now is when we are debugging locally and using swagger, we cannot pass a JWT token nor do we want to have to go  hit the auth service to refresh a token every 15 minutes.

How can i turn off authorization so that the [Authorize] does not do anything when we run locally effectively disabling the Authorization from happening?

Our code is setup as follows:

```
    services.AddAuthorization(x => x.DefaultPolicy =
                new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build());
services.AddAuthentication(x =>
            {
                x.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                x.DefaultForbidScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                x.DefaultSignInScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                x.DefaultSignOutScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

            }).AddJwtBearer(x =>
            {
                x.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateLifetime = true;
                x.TokenValidationParameters.IssuerSigningKey =
                    new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(jwtAuthKey));
                x.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateAudience = true;
                x.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = true;
                x.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true;
                x.TokenValidationParameters.ValidAudience = jwtIssuer;
                x.TokenValidationParameters.ValidIssuer = jwtIssuer;

            });
```

Then our controller has the authorize attribute on it. No matter what i do it still gives me a 401 unauthorized.

```
Authorize(Roles="Admin")
```

Comment: try extending `Authorize` attribute, return if `Request.IsLocal` property is true and sending to parent class for verification if not local.